# How to get all the pending http requests in javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, request, angular

Is there a way in javascript or angular2

to get the list of pending http requests?

The goal is to start 'several other processes'

according to the fluctuation of this list.

Does something like an accessible stack of requests exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can extend the `Http` class to intercept request execution.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http,ConnectionBackend,RequestOptions,RequestOptionsArgs,Request} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {MonitoringService} from './monitoring.service';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
              defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
              private monitoring:MonitoringService) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options);
  }

  (...)
}
```

You can leverage the `finally` operator to intercept the completion of observables corresponding to HTTP requests. You can increment a property before the call and decrement it in the `finally` operator.

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
  this.monitoring.pendingRequestsNumber++;
  return super.get(url, options).finally(() => {
    this.monitoring.pendingRequestsNumber--;
  });
}
```

This `CustomHttp` class can be registered like this. I added a monitoring service to store (and share) the number of pending requests:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS,Http,XHRBackend,RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CustomHttp} from './http.custom';
import {MonitoringService} from './monitoring.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  MonitoringService,
  provide(Http, {
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, monitory:MonitoringService) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, monitory),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, MonitoringService]
  })
]);
```

I created a plunkr describing the way to implement this approach: https://plnkr.co/edit/qHNn5amI0byci9RMkZyE?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on the backend if you want to do that. If your web site is hosted on php then you cannot do it in javascript. But if you use node.js then it is certainly possible because node.js uses javascript on the backend.

Comment: That's not always true, if you're making request on the front end you can certainly keep track of them manually at least

Comment: Ok if you are talking about request that you made from frontend then it should be easy to keep track of em with variables...

Comment: I tought he meant to get all the pending request from other users as well.